# como configurar uma tabela muito extensa

Tags: php, html, css

Como faço para mostrar um cadastro formulário por x na tabela?
a tabela e muito extensa como faço p mostrar ela como um formulário na vertical e não na horizontal?

```
    <CENTER><FONT COLOR=BLUE SIZE=6>TABELA</FONT></CENTER>  

    <table  BORDER RULES=all  CELLPADDING=10  ALIGN="center">


                    <tr >

                        <th>Nome</th>
                        <th>Fantasia</th>   
                        <th>Data Fundaçao</th>  
                        <th>Endereço</th>
                        <th>Complemento</th >
                        <th>Bairro</th>
                        <th>Cep</th>
                        <th>Estado</th>
                        <th>Cidade</th>
                        <th>Fone</th>
                        <th>Celular</th>
                        <th>CNPJ</th>
                        <th>Inscrição Estadual</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Contato</th>
                        <th>Data de Nascimento</th> 
                        <th>CPF</th>
                        <th>Endereço Residencial</th>
                        <th>Empresa</th>
                        <th>Fone</th>
                        <th>Empresa</th>
                        <th>Fone</th>
                        <th>Empresa</th>
                        <th>Fone</th>
                        <th>Banco</th>
                        <th>Agencia</th>
                        <th>Conta</th>
                        <th>Contato Banco</th>
                        <th>Fone</th>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>
            <?php while ($i<$qtd1){ ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $lista_cadastro[$i]->get("idcadastro"); ?>" 

                        </tr>               



                            <td >   
                                <?php                           
                                    echo $lista_cadastro[$i]->get("nome"); ?>                                      
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <?php echo $lista_cadastro[$i]->get("fantasia"); ?> 
                            </td>  

                            <td>
                                <?php echo $lista_cadastro[$i]->get("datafundacao"); ?> 
                            </td> 
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $lista_cadastro[$i]->get("endereco"); ?> 
                            </td> 
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $lista_cadastro[$i]->get("complemento"); ?> 
                            </td> 
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $lista_cadastro[$i]->get("bairro"); ?> 
                            </td> 
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $lista_cadastro[$i]->get("cep"); ?> 
                            </td> 

                            <td>
                                <?php echo $lista_cadastro[$i]->get("estado"); ?> 
                            </td> 
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $lista_cadastro[$i]->get("cidade"); ?> 
                            </td> 
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $lista_cadastro[$i]->get("fone"); ?> 
                            </td> 
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $lista_cadastro[$i]->get("celular"); ?> 
                            </td> 
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $lista_cadastro[$i]->get("cnpj"); ?> 
                            </td> 
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $lista_cadastro[$i]->get("inscricaoestadual"); ?> 
                            </td> 
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $lista_cadastro[$i]->get("email"); ?> 
                            </td> 
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $lista_cadastro[$i]->get("contato"); ?> 
                            </td> 
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $lista_cadastro[$i]->get("data_nascimento"); ?> 
                            </td> 
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $lista_cadastro[$i]->get("cpf"); ?> 
                            </td> 
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $lista_cadastro[$i]->get("enderecoresidencial"); ?> 
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $lista_cadastro[$i]->get("empresa"); ?> 
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $lista_cadastro[$i]->get("foneempresa"); ?> 
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $lista_cadastro[$i]->get("empresa1"); ?> 
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $lista_cadastro[$i]->get("fone1"); ?> 
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $lista_cadastro[$i]->get("empresa2"); ?> 
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $lista_cadastro[$i]->get("fone2"); ?> 
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $lista_cadastro[$i]->get("banco"); ?> 
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $lista_cadastro[$i]->get("agencia"); ?> 
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $lista_cadastro[$i]->get("conta"); ?> 
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $lista_cadastro[$i]->get("contatobanco"); ?> 
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $lista_cadastro[$i]->get("fonecontato"); ?> 

                            </td> 


                            </tr>                       

                        <?php $i++; 
                                    }?>
                        </table>



            <a href="../index.php?act=sair">Sair</a>        
            <div class="linhaFina"></div>           
            <td>

                <img src="imagens/editar_icon.jpg" alt="Editar" />
            </a>
        </td>
```

Comment: Oi Sérgio, bem vindo :)

Vamos lá, o quanto você conhece de PHP? Já consegues adicionar conteúdo em seu banco de dados e consulta-lo?

Comment: Coloque parte do código, uma imagem de como está e de como você pode melhorar o entendimento da pergunta. Use o link `editar` para adicionar mais detalhes na sua pergunta, aproveite e veja algumas dicas de como o site funciona na [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

Você deve fazer um `for` e ir adicionando linhas a sua tabela com as informações que retornaram do banco, vamos lá:

O código abaixo é responsável por gerar as linhas da tabela, o cabeçalho de tal deve ser declarado antes. Vamos supor que em seu banco de dados você possui uma tabela com as colunas ID e NOME.

```
// $registro receberá uma posição do array $registros a cada iteração 
<?php foreach ($registros as $registro) : ?>
    // vamos entao criar uma nova linha na tabela
    // dentro de cada linha teremos duas colunas
    <tr> 
        <td> <?php echo $registro['ID']; ?> </td>
        <td> <?php echo $registro['NOME']; ?> </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?> // encerramos o laço.
```

Bem simples, não? No caso, a cada repetição do `for` estamos criando uma linha nova, assim sua tabela irá "crescer" verticalmente.

Abraços e seja bem vindo.